# Calculate if Coordinates exist on straight line between 2 other coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to see if the Google Maps API supports the ability to see if:

1) There are 2 sets of coordinates, and basically draw a straight line route between them. This I can already do.

2) Check if a 3rd set of coordinates lies within x feet\meters of the drawn line.

If the API does not support this, any ideas as to how to determine this?  Thanks!

Comment: the geometry library offers isLocationOnEdge(): 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge

Answer (score 0):

We sneak up the distance by computing the area of a triangle two different ways.

Suppose you have three points, P1 = (x1, y1), P2 = (x2, y2), and P3 = (x3, y3). Your goal is to find out how close P3 is to the line joining P1, P2.

The area of that triangle is 1/2 the length of the cross-product of two sides. Ignore the 1/2 for now. Two sides are P2-P1 = (x2-x1, y2-y1) and P3-P1 = (x3-x1, y3-y1). (Imagine that all these points have a z-coordinate that is zero.) Then the only non-zero component of its cross-product is its z-coordinate, which has value z = (y2-y1)(x3-x1) - (x2-x1)(y3-y1). The area of the triangle is (half) the absolute value of this quantity z.

But we can also get the area by the traditional formula: one half the base times the height. The base is the (length of) the line from from P1 to P2. The dot product of P2-P1 is the square of that length, so b^2 = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2. (I'm having to write ^2 for "squared", because double-asterisk is turning on **bolding**.)

If we let h be the height of the triangle (that is, the distance from P3 to the line), then we have the area of the triangle two different ways: half of b*h, and half of abs(z). The halves cancel, and h = abs(z)/b. We just need to see if h is small enough.

To get b, we could calculate b^2 as above and take its square root, but it's simpler to square the equation instead: h^2 = abs(z)^2 / b^2. And now we don't even need to take the absolute value.

The computation reduces to:

```
z = (y2-y1)*(x3-x1) - (x2-x1)*(y3-y1)
bb = (x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1)
Test that z*z/bb is less than (3 feet) squared.
```

Be sure to keep track of units. The sides of the triangles are probably given to you in units other than feet. (And we also need to assume everything is close enough together that we can regard the map as flat. Spherical geometry is a whole 'nother ball of wax!)

There is one other wrinkle. You need to verify that P3 is not only close to the line, but also that the point on the line it's closest to falls between the endpoints. The easy way to do that is to check that the angles at P1 and P2 are acute, which you do by taking the dot products of the adjacent sides. The dot product will by positive iff the angle is acute.

```
Test that (x3-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y3-y1)*(y2-y1) > 0
Test that (x3-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y3-y2)*(y1-y2) > 0
```

Comment: I will digest this and get back to you.  Thanks!